# sql prevent duplicate entries

Tags: sql, insert, duplicates

I have 2 tables, Table1 & Table2
I need to insert values into Table2 where they do not exist in a table1 comparision.
Example: comparing Col1 values 1 & 2
Table1

```
Col1, Col2
1, 1
1, 2
1, 3
1, 4
2, 1
2, 5
3, 1
3, 2
```

I need to insert the following into Table2
2, 2 (based on 1, 2)
2, 3 (based on 1, 3)
2, 4 (based on 1, 4)
However Table2 must not have duplicate records.  Unique keys are not an option.

Comment: `However Table2 must not have duplicate records. Unique keys are not an option.` Famous last words ...

Comment: So what is your question? Add a unique index and go on

Comment: Cannot find my crystal ball. You need to elaborate a bit. Are you saying that you need to convert e.g. `INSERT INTO table2 (SELECT col1 + 1, col2 FROM table1);` ?